# Creating two arrays from a series in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a series (saved as series in my code) and want to save its values into two different arrays using python. The first six values I want to save in an array called `x`, where:

`series[0] = x[0,0], series[1] = x[0,1], series[2] = x[0,2], series[3] = x[0,3], series[4] = x[0,4], series[5] = x[0,5], series[6] = x[0,6]`.

Now switch to `series[7] = y[0]`. Then repeat and create a new row in `x`:
 `series[8] = x[1,0], series[9] = x[1,1], series[10] = x[1,2], series[11] = x[1,3], series[12] = x[1,4], series[13] = x[1,5], series[14] = x[1,6]`.
Now switch to `series[14] = y[1]` and continue.

I have only been able to read in the .csv file and convert it from a dataframe to a series. I think this problem can be solved using nested for loops but have been unable to figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

series = df['totalBuildingEnergykW_EVERLY_HALL_BUILDING_ENERGY_EnergyMetric']
```

[image: Series Snippet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a better idea to use df['Column_name'].tolist() function to get data from a dataframe's column into a list as this gives you data in list format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.read_csv("File.csv")
L = df['column_name'].tolist() 
w, h = 6, 2;
Arr = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 
for i,item in enumerate(L):
    if i<6 :
         Arr[0][i] = item
    else :
         Arr[1][i-6] = item
```

Comment: That Arr line is how you intialize a multi_dimensional array

Comment: Thanks for your help!